# load balancer in Spring boot, ignores failing servers

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, httpresponse

I have a load balancer in Spring boot, but I want that when one of the servers fails, it ignores it and uses another

so for example if the second localhost fails, i will like it to try to use another, without the user notice, that there is a server down, ¿what can i do?

so i am usign this

```
@Override
  public Flux<List<ServiceInstance>> get() {
    return Flux.just(Arrays
        .asList(
          new DefaultServiceInstance(serviceId + "1", serviceId, "localhost", 8080, false),
            new DefaultServiceInstance(serviceId + "2", serviceId, "localhost", 9092, false),
            new DefaultServiceInstance(serviceId + "3", serviceId, "localhost", 9999, false)));
  }
}
```

To tell my code all the posibles servers, but when one fails, it shows an error, and i will like that it tries another server, instead of showing HTTP response 500, so the user will not notice ther was an error in the first place

Comment: You wrote a load balancer??? Did any of the dozens of software and hardware LBs in the market not serve the purpose?

Comment: Are you checking heartbeat of those servers ? so you will know which one is available, which is not.